# How does one pronounce "dwam"?

Tags: pronunciation

How should *dwam* be pronounced? As spelt? Or more educated - with  'R' or L' in the middle...?

Comment: It's an English word? Who knew?

Answer (score 3):

This depends **entirely** on accent, although it's difficult to see how even rhotic accents could put *r* in it.

OED has

> - British English /dwɑːm/
> - American English /dwɑm/
> - Scottish English /dwam/

Those are all more of an *ah* sound than a short *cat/dam* sound.

For the interested, OED also has

> *Scottish and northern dialect.*
> ?a1513–
> A swoon, a fainting fit.
> *In Glossaries of East Yorkshire.*
>
> > ?a1513
> > Sic deidlie dwawmes so mischeifaislie..hes my hairt ouirpast. [W. Dunbar, Poems (1998) vol. I. 125]
> > 1892
> > *Dwalm,* a slight illness, a faint fit. [R. O. Heslop, *Northumberland Words*]

The spelling with *l* might make a difference to the pronunciation.

Comment: It's not clear from that if the "l" in "dwalm" is pronounced, or just to indicate a long /ɑː/ vowel in that example. But the [Dictionaries of the Scots Language](https://dsl.ac.uk/entry/snd/dwam) entry has several variants of "dwam" including "dwalm", "dwaum", "dwawm" but doesn't indicate a pronunciation different to /dwɑ:m/, so I'd guess there is no /l/ in any variants.

Comment: @StuartF Maybe some of those spellings with "extra" letters might be that way to try to indicate they have the same vowel as *dawn* does? I honestly couldn't say because I'm not a Scot and have never heard this word said aloud by a native speaker.

Comment: @tchrist: I don’t think it’s the same vowel as *dawn*, it’s the same vowel as *calm* and *palm*, which in the U.K. are pronounced with the vowel of *father*  and not of *ram* or of *dawn*.

Comment: I grew up in Scotland with very literate parents.  I heard it pronounced as 'dwarm'